# Prove that the operator norm is a norm

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Exercise: Prove that the operator norm of the set $S$ of all linear operators $L:R^n\to R^m$ defines a norm on $S$

Definition of norm: A positive function $\| .\|$ on a real vector space $V$ is a norm if

- $\|v\|=0$ if and only if $v=0$
- $\|\lambda v\|=|\lambda|\|v\|$ for all $\lambda\in R$ and $v\in V$
- $\|v+w\|\le\|v\|+\|w\|$ for all $v,w\in V$

Definition of operator norm: $\|L\|=sup_{a\ne 0}\|La\|/\|a\|$ or $=sup_{\|a\|=1}\|La\|$

First part (successful, I think):

- if $\|L\|=0$, we have $sup_{\|a\|=1}\|La\|=0$, so $L=0$.
- if $L=0$, we have $sup_{\|a\|=1}\|0a\|=0$

Second part (unsuccessful):

- $\|\lambda L\|=sup_{\lambda a\ne 0}\|\lambda La\|/\|\lambda a\|=sup_{\lambda a\ne 0}\lambda \|La\|/\lambda \|a\|=sup_{a\ne 0}\|La\|/\|a\|\ne |\lambda|\|L\|$

Third part (successful, I think):

- $\|L(v+w)\|=sup_{\|v+w\|=1}\|Lv+Lw\|\le sup_{\|v\|=1}\|Lv\|+sup_{\|w\|=1}\|Lw\|=\|v\|+\|w\|$

Suggestions? Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: In the second part it should be $ ||\lambda L a||/||a||=|\lambda||| L a||/||a|| $.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be 
$$ \|\lambda L \| = \sup_{a \ne 0} \dfrac{\|\lambda L a\|}{\|a\|} = \ldots $$

Answer (score 0):

Second part is as Robert says.
Third part is wrong, you have to prove that $$\|L_1+L_2\|\leq \|L_1\|+\|L_2\|.$$ Hint: use that $\|\cdot\|_{R^n}$ is a norm.